# unable to post via graph api php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following in my scope parameter -> 'email,publish_stream';
and the permission is granted by the user. But, I am unable to post to the user's wall via graph api.

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['publish'])){
    try{
        $publishStream = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
            'message'       => 'Example',
            'link'          => 'http://example.com',
            'picture'       => 'http://example.com/75x75.png',
            'name'          => 'Example website',
            'caption'       => 'example.com',
            'description'       => 'A Technology Laboratory. Highly   
Recomented technology blog.',
            ));
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        error_log($e);
    }
}

// Update user's status using graph api
if(isset($_POST['status'])){
    try{
        $statusUpdate = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post',             
array('message'=> $_POST['status']));
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        error_log($e);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: whats in your error log?

Comment: you should use `error_log($e->getType()); error_log($e->getMessage());` and then have a look what the errors are

Comment: nothing is being shown after adding the code... :(

Comment: Where is `$user` coming from in your code? (And why don’t you just use `/me` instead?)

Answer (score 0):

Usually I do something like this:

```
$response = $facebook->api('/'.$fanpage.'/feed?access_token='.$fanpage_token, 'POST',
                                array(
                                  'message' => $result['message'],
                                  'link' => $result['link']
                             ));
```

Try passing the access token directly into the $_GET.

**Read the details:**
$response - this stores the response of the facebook api
$facebook this came from the following:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
      'secret' => YOUR_SECRET_KEY,
));
```

$fanpage - this is the fanpage id i'm posting to

$fanpage_token - this is the fanpage access token i'm using (to be able to manage the page)

$result['message'] - this is a result coming from database with a message to be posted on the page

$result['link'] - this is a link i'm attaching to the message to be posted

Comment: It's not working shows fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) link URL is not properly formatted thrown in ...

Comment: What link are you passing in? Check if your domain is included in Authorized Domains and that your URL is correct. Are you trying to post an image or just a link? If it is an image, is it to be posted in an album or in the wall of a user/page?

Comment: You need to modify my code. This is just how I'm doing it. Gonna add some more details on the post.

Comment: Did you modify the settings? What error does it show now? The same?

Comment: Is your domain authorized in App Settings?

Answer (score -1):

http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/

The API changed. Its not possible to publish in wall with graph api. Use Feed Dialog.

Comment: That is only for users other then the current user.